# how to show media files on recycler view from a specific device folder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mediastore

Hello Guys need a help

This is my requirement:-

1. I have a folder in my device
2. there are different types of files in that
3. wanna load these all files on a recycler view (only display)

Please guide me I am a beginner in android development

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Things get complicated for android 10 and even more so for android 11 in terms of file access. Read up on Scoped Storage and Storage Access Framework (SAF)

This piece of code checks through a folder and looks for directories. I hope this will give some ideas

```
   private void    getDir(String dirPath) throws IOException {
    fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    strpath = dirPath;
    setTitle(strpath);
    String rootItem = "";
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    DocumentFile pickedDir = fio.getDocumentFileIfAllowedToWrite(f, mContext);

    if (pickedDir != null) {
        DocumentFile dfile[] = pickedDir.listFiles();
        if (!dirPath.equals("/")) {
            rootItem = dirPath;
        }
        if (null != dfile) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dfile.length; i++) {
                DocumentFile file = dfile[i];
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    if (file.canRead()) {
                        String next_part = dfile[i].getName();
                        try {
                            fileNames.add(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + next_part);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (tracks.checkAndroidAudioFormat(file.getName())) {
                        fileNames.add(file.getName());
                    }
                }
            }// end of loop
            Collections.sort(fileNames, new Comparator<String>() {
                public int compare(String obj1, String obj2) {
                    return obj1.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2);
                }
            });
            // now insert root at position1
            fileNames.add(0, rootItem);
            mAdapter = new browseLocalFoldersAdapter(
                    browseLocalFoldersActivity.this, fileNames);
            mAdapter.initializearray(fileNames.size());
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // triggers onPrepareOptionsMenu etc.
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }else{

     //   FragmentManager manager = getParentFragmentManager();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FilePickerDialog dialog = new FilePickerDialog();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("ACTION_CODE", 0);
        b.putString("COMMENT", getString(R.string.setpermissions));
        b.putString("BUTTON", getString(R.string.set_sdcard_permissions));
        b.putInt("OPEN_INTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE", OPEN_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        dialog.setArguments(b);
//        dialog.setTargetFragment(this, OPEN_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        dialog.show(manager, "OPEN_INTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE");





    }
}
```